# How to create a report in python which computes difference of rows of a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new with Python & Pandas & trying to devise a solution for the problem I am describing below.
I have a pandas data frame which I am reading from a table & it looks like this

```
     source        date         qty
0       A        2020-07-27      53307994.0
1       B        2020-07-27      53307994.0
2       C        2020-07-27      53307994.0
```

Now what I want to do is, to create a report wherein I will need to compute the difference between source A and B and source A & C.
My result should look something like

```
QTY_DIFF               
2020-07-27        A_B_Diff    B_C_Diff
qty                 0           0
```

What I have been able to do so far is get an additional column with the difference but can't figure out next step.

```
     source        date         qty             diff
0       A        2020-07-27      53307994.0      0
1       B        2020-07-27      53307994.0      0
2       C        2020-07-27      53307994.0      0
```

Comment: How many sources do you have? Would you like to have a new column for any combination of two sources, or just for some?

Comment: @Roy2012 I have multiple sources,7 to be precise & yes, I would like to add a new column for any combination of two sources.

Comment: @PeeyushPathak you want to find diff between A&B and A&C and A&D so on so forth ?

Comment: @Hussain Yes I want exactly that.

Comment: So you're looking for 21 new columns - the difference between any two sources of the 7 you have?

Comment: @Roy2012 I am sorry I misunderstood when you said between any two columns, what I need is the difference between A-B, B-C, C-D, D-E & so on.

Comment: @Hussain I am sorry I misunderstood when you said between any two columns, what I need is the difference between A-B, B-C, C-D, D-E & so on. So it should be 6 new columns

Comment: Okay got it. You want the difference between 2 consecutive rows. so what is the next step which you can't figure out? is how you want `QTY_DIFF               
2020-07-27        A_B_Diff    B_C_Diff
qty                 0           0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pivot function for the desired result:

```
df.pivot(index='date', columns='source', values='diff')
```

output:

```
source      A   B   C
date            
2020-07-27  0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you would want to pivot 1st followed by performing your subtractions:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

```
df.pivot(index='date', columns='source', values='qty')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with `pivot_table` and `diff`, demonstrated with synthetic data.

Input:

```
            qty source
date                  
2020-07-01   11      D
2020-07-01   11      E
2020-07-01   16      A
2020-07-01   18      E
2020-07-01   13      B
2020-07-01   11      E
2020-07-02   14      A
2020-07-02   17      D
2020-07-02   17      C
2020-07-03   10      E
2020-07-03   17      A
2020-07-03   11      E
2020-07-03   17      D
2020-07-03   17      A
2020-07-03   18      B
```

Code:

```
piv = pd.pivot_table(df, columns="source", index = "date")
piv = piv.diff(axis=1)
piv.columns = piv.columns.droplevel(0)
new_cols = [f"{c1}-{c2}" for c1, c2 in zip(piv.columns, piv.columns[1:])]
piv.drop("A", axis=1, inplace = True)
piv.columns = new_cols
```

The output is:

```
            A-B  B-C  C-D       D-E
date                               
2020-07-01 -3.0  NaN  NaN  2.333333
2020-07-02  NaN  NaN  0.0       NaN
2020-07-03  1.0  NaN  NaN -6.500000
```